# How to link the anchor tags inside the table to a js function?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tags, anchor

Hi :) I need some help for this. I have a problem on how to show my modals in simply clicking the "View Location" button inside the table. Once I hit it the modals will show but I cant do this. Here' s my code:

```
echo "<td><a href='');\">View Location</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='editPeople.php?id=".$query2['ID']."');\">Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='deletePeople.php?id=".$query2['ID']."' onClick=\"javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');\">Delete</a></td><tr>";
```

This is my js coming from the free source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ic() {
$("#btnShow").click(function ic() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Google Map",
        width: 600,
        hright: 450,
        buttons: {
            Close: function ic() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        open: function ic() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.8527393, 120.8160376),
                zoom: 18,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map($("#dvMap")[0], mapOptions);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

My problem is in this part echo "View Location";
I have no idea to make it functional. Is anyone here knows how to solve this? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you using PHP for creating table ? looks like yes. If you are aware of it then i need to correct the PHP code otherwise need to remove it...

Comment: @YPS Yes I am using PHP for creating tables.

Comment: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css

Those two links are not working for me. make sure its working for code

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP try this:

```
echo "<td><button id="btnShow">View Location</button></td>";
echo "<td><a href='editPeople.php?id=".$query2['ID']."');\">Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='deletePeople.php?id=".$query2['ID']."' onClick=\"javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');\">Delete</a></td><tr>";


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#btnShow").click(function ic() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Google Map",
        width: 600,
        hright: 450,
        buttons: {
            Close: function ic() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        open: function ic() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.8527393, 120.8160376),
                zoom: 18,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map($("#dvMap")[0], mapOptions);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I try it but still its not working. Its just a simple button w/o a  function :(

Comment: yeah! jquery function $("#btnShow").click() will work automatically while you click on it. In javascript you need to call function explicit. it is jquery.

Comment: also Please check your console for any error. let us know if any error is there...

Comment: can you pls help me on how to do that? I am a begginer in web development -_-

Comment: open DevTool (CTRL+F12) then click on console tab. then refresh you site. this panel will list js error there if any.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery syntax `$("#btnShow").click` is saying "When something with an ID of btnShow is clicked."

Therefore, by giving your link an ID of btnShow,  you'll cause the function to fire.

```
echo "<td><a href='' id='btnShow'>View Location</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='editPeople.php?id=".$query2['ID']."');\">Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='deletePeople.php?id=".$query2['ID']."' onClick=\"javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');\">Delete</a></td><tr>";
```

If you want the button to have a hand cursor, you may want `echo "<td><a style='cursor: pointer;' href='' id='btnShow'>View Location</a></td>";`

**EDIT:** I think I've misunderstood. If you're trying to popup a location based on the person, and not have the page change windows, you'll have to do this through AJAX.

The PHP would be something like:

```
echo "<td><a href='' onclick='btnShow(".$query2['ID'].")'>View Location</a></td>";
```

Essentially what the code above does now is call a jquery function called "btnShow(ID)" which you'd have to create. This function would do an AJAX call to a PHP page that grabs the latitude and longitude from a server based on the ID you've passed. On success, it would then call your 'free source' formula, replacing the latitude and longititude with the values retrieved from the AJAX call.

I realize this sounds daunting but jQuery makes AJAX calls much easier than they sound. I wish I had more time at the moment to type out a function for you, however I do not. I hope this at least moved you in the right direction though!

**EDIT 2:** To be clear, the function that you're calling right now - the free source one - has a set latitude and longitude. No matter what "View Location" button you click, it will ALWAYS show the same location. If you're trying to do this, then I can give you a simple script.

However, if you're trying to change location based on the person, this is way more in depth, and would be achieved using the method I've outlined in my original edit.

Comment: modals did not show. Still execute the same page because of a href = ' '. Its not working.

Comment: The page should not change. The function you posted from the free source is on the same page as the table, yes?

Add this line of code before `$("#dialog").dialog({` to see if the function is being called:

`alert("btnShow has been clicked.");`

Comment: nothing happen. I feel so hopeless :( im so pressure right now coz as of this moment my "view location" button is useless. By the way its a school project :) thats why i am hoping that someone here could help me. Thanks anyway